# Wordpress advanced navigation

Tags: wordpress-theming

Ok, so I've made a site template in pure html and I need to convert it into wordpress. The navigation code looks like this:

```
    <div id="header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <ul id="leftnav">
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
                <li><a href="work.html">Work</a><span class="arrow"/></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="logo"> 
                <h1><a href="index.html">T.Wiersema</a></h1>
                <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <ul id="rightnav">
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a><span class="arrow"/></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a><span class="arrow"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The leftnav is absolutely positioned to the left and right nav is absolutely positioned to the right with the logo centered between the two. Notice also how I have a span inside each li element. Is there a way to reproduce this in my wordpress theme without just manually copying this into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have WP generate a list of links to pages on your site, however it doesn't always suit the purpose, particularly in this case. If this is a theme for your own site, just hard-code the links and be done with it; wrangling the auto-generated list will probably be more trouble than it is worth. This seems to be common consensus in related discussion I have seen.

Comment: that's too bad...I was hoping Wordpress would have some amazing navigation function that would do this...oh well. Thanks for answering...seems no one else could answer this one. :-)